# Media query with slicknav not showing up and aligning my other menu to the center at the bottom of my web page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to complete this web page for an intro web development course at my university. Right now, I'm having problems trying to get my slicknav menu to show up as well as getting my bottom menu in my side div class to center when I change the screen size. Ideally, I'm trying to get it to pop up below my header when the screen gets smaller.

I needed to drop the side menu to the bottom of the page, so I switched to a grid layout and called it wrapper, but now my slick nav menu isn't showing up. I've also tried to reference my bottom menu by using .side as well as #side-menu, but I can't get it to become wider or center itself with self-align or by manually padding it.

Here is the relevant code below. I've attached the link to my webhost as well if you want to check out everything. Please help me! I am so frustrated :(

https://knemes.000webhostapp.com/halloween_starts_ch8/index.html

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class = "header">
        <header>
            <img src="images/pumpkin.gif" alt="pumpkin" width="85px"/>
            <h2>The Halloween Store</h2>
            <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
        </header>
    </div>


<div class="menu">
    <nav id="mobile_menu"></nav>
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Decorating Ideas</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Treats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Join Email</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
</div>

<div class="side">
    <ul id ="side-menu">
        <li><a href="../public_html/halloween_starts/slides/products/props">Props</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public_html/halloween_starts/slides/products/costumes">Costumes</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public_html/halloween_starts/slides/products/special_effects">Special FX</a></li>
        <li><a href="../public_html/halloween_starts/slides/products/masks">Masks</a></li>
    </ul>      
</div>
```

As well as this right before the end of my body tag

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        prependTo:'#mobile_menu'
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.header {grid-area: header;}
.menu {grid-area: menu;}
.side {grid-area: side;}
.section {grid-area: section;}
.footer {grid-area: footer;}

/*side bar*/
.side {
    padding-top: 1.3em 0;
    width: 10.94em;
    float: left;
}

.side ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.side li {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    border: .13em solid black;
    background-color: orange;
}

.side li a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em 0 .5em .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: black;
}


#mobile_menu{
    display:none;
}

.slicknav_menu{
    display:none;
}


/*media queries*/
@media (max-width:800px) {

    html {
        background: none;
    }

    body {
        box-shadow: none;
        font-size: 90%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .wrapper{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "menu"
            "section"
            "side"
            "footer";
    }

    .side{
        align-self: center;
    }

    html {
        background: none;  

    }

    header h2 {
        font-size: 200%;
        text-indent: 0;
    }

    header h3{
        text-indent: 0;
    }

    body {
        box-shadow: none;
        font-size: 90%;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    section{
        width: auto;
        padding: 5%;
    }

    header img{
        float: left;
    }


    #menu {
        display: none;
    }

    #mobile_menu{
        display:block;
    }


}

@media (max-width: 479px) {

    header h2 {
        margin-top: .5em;
        text-indent: 10px;
        font-size: 1.7em;
    }

    header h3 {
        margin-top: 0;
        text-indent: 0;
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }

    main > h1 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    main > h1:first-child::first-letter {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

Basically, this is what I'm trying to achieve when the screen gets smaller. As you can see, I'm almost there! I just need some help finishing up.

[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx6XU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change `display:grid` to `display:block` in media query as shown below:

```
 @media (max-width: 767px){
    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas: "header"
     "menu"
     "section"
     "side"
     "footer";
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi! I tried that, but it didn't help :( My side menu is now at the top and my slick nav menu still won't pop up when the screen shortens